# How to make a method pause its execution until a previously called method with async callbacks completes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application wherein the user enters a sentence in a text box. I use the TextBox.Text method to get the text in the TextBox as a string and I call a method getTranslation() which internally invokes several async callbacks as it requires

- establish connection to server
- write request to POST Stream
- Get response callback from server
- Process the response
- return the response to the xaml page

In the xaml page of the application I first call the first method passing the input text as param. Then the next line of code calls the return response method and sets the TextBlock content to the returned response.

These are my methods used to call the server.

```
public void searchOnline(string inputtxt)
        {
        //Lines of code
            IAsyncResult writeRequestStreamCallback =
              (IAsyncResult)req.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(RequestStreamReady), req);
         }
        private void RequestStreamReady(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
        //Lines of code
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }
        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
           //Lines of code
                IAsyncResult writeRequestStreamCallback = (IAsyncResult)serviceWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ServiceReady), serviceWebRequest);
         }
        private void ServiceReady(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
        //Lines of code
            System.IO.StreamReader streamRead = new System.IO.StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            searchresult = responseString;
        }

        public string returner()
        {
            return searchresult;
        }
```

In the xaml page I call the following code

```
help.searchOnline(inputtextbox.Text);//line 1
                               outputtextbox.Text = help.returner();//line 2
                               outputtextbox.UpdateLayout();
```

My problem is how to make the return method in the xaml page wait i.e. line 2, to update the textblock, till the response is received i.e. until line 1 updates the search result string?

Answer (score 0):

Only rewrite methods synchronously. You just want to continue running the program with the display in OutputTextBox. Therefore, the process for acquiring the data should be awaited.

But if you need to perform other operations during this process, you can use a Task:
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Through this class you can assign an object (TResult) to the return of the operation, so check your state and proceed the way you want, for example through the property:

`public bool IsCompleted {get; }`

Which would tell you if the SearchOnline is complete!

In addition to this property, there are methods such as Wait, thats literally waits for the Task to complete execution i.e, await the method SearchOnline to update the OutputTextBox.

I would like to reiterate that it would be very good to study the features of Class System.Threading.Tasks.Task.

I Hope it helps :)